# Why can't this logical statement be proved?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the following, I don't see how the second statement is different from the fourth one.

I think that we can prove 21 is a natural number in the same manner that we can prove 2 is.

Would you explain why the second statement can be proved and the fourth cannot or how they are different? Thank you.

---

The following English statements are logical statements:

- 0 is a natural number
- 2 is a natural number
- For all *x*, if *x* is a natural number, then so is the successor of *x*.
- 21 is a natural number

Predicate calculus:

```
 natural(0).
 natural(2).
 For all x, natural(x) → natural(successor(x))
 natural(21).
```

Among these logical statements, the first and third can be viewed as **axioms** for the natural numbers: statements that are assumed to be true and from which all true statements about natural numbers can be **proved**. The second statement can be proved:

`2 = successor(successor(0)) and natural(0) → natural(sucessor(0)) → natural(successor(successor(0))).`

The fourth statement, on the other hand, cannot be proved from the axioms and so can assumed to be false.

Comment: What makes you think that the fourth statement can't be proven assuming the first and third.

Comment: @CodeInChaos The text below the horizontal line is from my textbook. I'm thinking it can be.

Comment: That seems wrong. Could be a typo? ie meant to say "2.1". But I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning. 2 and 21 are, qualitatively, the same.

Comment: @Jubbat Thank you. I found the [errata](http://academic.cengage.com/resource_uploads/downloads/1111529418_276155.pdf) which says "natural(21)" should be "natural(-1)", so if you would like to make your comment an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Nice, it had to be a mistake, but the merit of finding it is not mine. You can set your question as answered with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon some comments I searched for the [errata](http://academic.cengage.com/resource_uploads/downloads/1111529418_276155.pdf) which says `natural(21)` should be `natural(-1)`. So it was indeed a typo.